# get textfield value from dynamically generated list without AJAX

Tags: php

I have been searching for days and must be missing something.

I have a bunch of textfields that are generated based on a selection. So sometimes I have 5 fields others 20. (it is a list of names).  The user can then add a new one, delete one or I want them to be able to update the name (if it is spelled wrong).

My issue is I don't know how to get the updated data from the specific textfield. I have a link UPDATE next to each text box. I can do it if there is just one textfield, but once I have more than 1 I have no idea how to tell it which one.

The other challenge I am trying to do this without using AJAX, only php.

Used to Generate the textfield
" size="40" />

Comment: Name the update button with a name that tells you which field they are trying to update? I don't know it is hard to advise you when there is no code. Can you show us a minimized example?

Comment: I could use a button also, which I prefer, however each time the page is generated there would be a different number of buttons and they are generated from the code (<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>)
My output would look like this
John Doe Player Delete Update
Jane Doe Mgr. Delete Update
Etc.
I never know how many rows there will be, it depends on how many names the user enters. I can use buttons if I know how many rows there are, just not sure how to do it if they are created dynamically.

THANKS for any help!

Comment: Here is the code to generate the table and delete that works(I know I need to change recordset1 to something meaningful, just trying to get it working first).
        <td width="284"><input name="player_name" type="text" id="player_name" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Name']; ?>" size="40" /></td>
        <td width="98"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Title']; ?></td>
        <td width="93"><a href="Roster_delete.php?Id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>&amp;teamname=<?php echo $TeamNameTemp ?>">
        Delete</a></td>